# How to setup cmake on windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, visual-studio-2013, cmake

I'm trying to compile a program that requires Cmake and boost on windows. I installed visual studio 2013 express and I cant get cmake to compile the program.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 11 Win64" ..

-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknow
CMake Error in :
No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error in :
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

Comment: have you actually run "Configure" on the cmake file? you might also consider using cmake-gui.exe

Comment: When I run configure it says "error in configuration process"   Edit: this apears to be the error when I ran configure                        error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Comment: Well that seems to indicate that something is wrong with the cmake file. In that case I would ask the author of the program for help

Comment: The main thing here is i have no issues compiling it for linux and I know that others have compiled the same source with no problems.

Comment: Well that does not change the fact that configure is failing for you (for whatever reason), and therefore you cannot generate a visual studio project. The best person to ask would still be the author of the program as she/he might now what can cause this error

Comment: `Visual Studio 11 Win64` is the wrong generator for Visual Studio 2013. I believe you need `Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64` if you are using cmake-3.x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Visual Studio 11 Win64** is the wrong generator for Visual Studio 2013. You need to use **Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64** if you are using cmake-3.x or **Visual Studio 12 Win64** for cmake-2.8.x.  A list of the [visual studio generators is here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#ide-build-tool-generators).

Comment: I realized that late last night. I still have to figure out what I did wrong when I installed boost though.